# HTACCESS url rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite this url and it just doesn't seem to be working and I am unclear what is going wrong

I want this URL:

```
www.mysite.com/dvd-123/Studio/studio_name.php?thumbs=yes&order=price
```

To actually send to:

```
www.mysite/cat/list_products.php?studio=123&store=dvd&thumbs=yes&order=price
```

Here is what I have that is sorta working:

```
RewriteRule ^dvd-([0-9]+)/Studio/(.*)\.php?(.*)$ cat/list_products.php?studio=$1&store=dvd&$3 [L]
```

The results I am receiving are the same as if i want to:
    www.mysite/cat/list_products.php?studio=123&store=dvd
ignoring the:
    &thumbs=yes$order=price

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

> The Pattern will not be matched against the query string... To combine a new query string with an old one, use the [QSA] flag.

I haven't tested this, but hopefully it should point you in the right direction.

```
RewriteRule ^dvd-([0-9]+)/Studio/(.*)\.php$ cat/user_list_products.php?Manname=$1&store=dvd [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I am checking it out, QSA flag is causing an error 500.  I hate .htaccess ahaha I never had any desire to learn how to do this, just had a client request it.

Comment: QSA Flag is the key !! Test your regex with : rubular.com

Comment: I fixed it, not sure how, i removed the [L] and it worked!  So clearly i was doing something wrong that one of my later rules caught haha.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the slashes.

```
RewriteRule ^dvd-([0-9]+)\/Studio\/(.*)\.php?(.*)$ cat/user_list_products.php?Manname=$1&store=dvd&supersale=$3 [L]
```